# Insert name tags in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, tags, spreadsheet

I found out that you can tag people inside a cell of google spreadsheet by type in "@" and then the name. Google will also suggest people after you typed the "@".

It looks like so: https://ibb.co/YkymjLJ

Is it possible to insert the tags with google apps script? Is there a method something like sheet.getRange(1,1).setNameTag("John Doe") ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible at this time, though has been requested:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=apps%20script%20people%20chips